# Convert model to Lagrangean decomposition algorithm

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I am not very familiar with modeling and I am new. I have written a model in the field of production planning as follows and it is in the category of large scale problems. And I wanted to solve it with one of the exact methods. I wanted to convert the following model into Lagrangean decomposition algorithm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHny6.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos   Thanks for your guidance. I tried to edit it in the best way I could.